# How to save all the resources that are sent to a browser?

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I have a same site deployed on 2 different servers, The source files on the servers are identical, so I have to assume what is being sent by webservers on servers are different, as one has javascript that works in IE11 and the other server sends something that breaks the Javascript on the very same page and input (posted data).

How do I either save all the resources sent to a request or use IE11 F12 tools to save all the received resources?

Is there any tools for emulating browsers and saving all the sent responses to disk? (I tried saving the network traffic in IE11 to disk , but there are details about reponse times etc, that are making a compare extremely difficult).

Comment: I assume you've compared the "View Page Source" from both servers? Are the webservers the same version? For example, same version of IIS if you are using that?

Comment: I was going to do a complete response compare, but now that you mention it I'll do a view source compare. There are 2 different versions of IIS running on servers.

Comment: Different versions of IIS may render page output substantially differently, especially for complex server-side controls like GridView and such. Comparing the "View Page Source" would be the first place to start. The Javascript breakage is much more likely to be due to a page's controls rendering differently (or unexpectedly) than it is to be due to the script itself being corrupted or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save all the files delivered by the server to IE11 by clicking the **Page** button, then choosing **Save As**.  Select **Web Page, complete** to save all the files.

The first thing to check would be to use the IE developer tools to watch for errors as the page loads.

- Corrected due to comment - thank you

Comment: All good points, although this doesn't sound like a browser compatibility issue. I imagine OP is using the same browser for both sites. This is more likely due to IIS version changes in how certain server-side controls are rendered into HTML. The OP's Javascript likely depends on a fragile, predefined tag structure or tag IDs.